Javascript / Selenium webdriver - Can't focus on an HTML5 element
I have this webpage structure:

When button with an id addProfButton is pressed like this:

Javascript:
document.getElementById("addProfButton").click();


C# Selenium webdriver:
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("addProfButton")).Click();



a popup window with id AddProfileDialog appears. This div element (indicated by a brown rectangle) does not exist before the click.
This element has a sub-element, an input field with id ItbInputName, which I have to select and then input text inside. After this, I have to click button with id btnAddConfirmOk, which is also part of the popup window.
To achieve this, firstly I have to click inside the input field:

Javascript:
document.getElementById("ItbInputName").click();


C# Selenium webdriver:
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ItbInputName")).Click();



To my amazement, this does not work... Why? How can I make it work?

Could you elaborate what is happening, are you getting some kind of error or is it just simply not working. Does the pop up appear?
Also you please check your button id spelling your code has an uppercase i, i.e "I" whereas the html code says it should be a lowercase L i.e "l".

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. This includes HTML.

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

With the minimal code you've posted, it's hard to tell what the issue is with certainty but if the steps involve clicking a button that opens a popup and you don't have a wait, that's most likely the issue.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("addProfButton"))).Click();
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("ItbInputName"))).SendKeys("some text");

